# Select rows from a DataFrame based on a single float column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below.I need to select all rows for which the value of first column named **index** is less than 0.3768.

I have found some answers in stack over flow,but none of them is working in my case
[image]

I tried to create a data frame which contains all rows where the column(**named index as shown in yellow**) value .Below is my code it is throwing some error.May I know where I went wrong.

```
df2 = df_thd_funct_mode2_perf['index'] <= 0.3768
df2
```

The error obtained is given below.

'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: please paste the data directly and format as code. Don't upload images

Comment: `df_thd_funct_mode2_perf.loc[df_thd_funct_mode2_perf['index'].astype(float) <= 0.3768]`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
df2 = df_thd_funct_mode2_perf[df_thd_funct_mode2_perf['index'] <= 0.3768]
```

A short explanation:

We're saying here: Take all of the rows and columns of `df_thd_funct_mode2_perf` for which `[df_thd_funct_mode2_perf['index'] <= 0.3768]` and then save this to df2

Comment: Thank you, it is giving me only the 0th row .I need all the rows where index less than 0.3768

Comment: Ah, this is because the column is name index and using df.index takes the index instead. I've updated the answer accordingly. The code will now work.